# Возвращение request https java при ошибке

Tags: java, url, request, httpsurlconnection

Есть такой код

```
   private String getAnswer(String link, String post) throws Exception {
        URL aURL = new URL(link);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();
        try {
            if(checkResponseCode(conn.getResponseCode())) return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())).readLine();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())).readLine());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Когда сайт к которому обращается код, кидает ERROR 404 он возвращает Resposne 404 + программа по коду идет в Catch и вместо того чтобы выдать `<html><body> 404 Not Found </body> </html>`
Выдает Exeption типа:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: URL по которому идем
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
```

---

При попытке зайти в туже страницу через CURL получаем  `<html><body> 404 Not Found </body> </html>`.

**Вопрос:**
Как прочитать настоящий ответ от сайта по примеру.

По факту это API который отсылает JSON который мы парсим, и он в случе ошибок в запросе кидает код 400, и ошибку в виде STRING но я ее не могу увидеть т.к. мне в консоли ее не пишет.

---

```
   if (responcecode >= 400 && responcecode < 500 && responcecode != 429 && responcecode != 418) {
        System.out.println("BAD REQUEST");
        return false;
    }
    if (responcecode >= 500 && responcecode < 600 && responcecode != 504) {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
        return false;
    }
    switch (responcecode) {
        case 429:
            System.out.println("WARNING! REQUESTLIMIT FULL");
            return false;
        case 418:
            System.out.println("WARNING! IP BLOCK");
            return false;
        case 504:
            System.out.println("WARNING!FAILED");
            return false;
        case 200:
            return true;
        default:
            System.out.println("Ops. Help me! I don't know what i do now!");
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что фактически возвращает `conn.getResponseCode()`?

Comment: true \ false  = true если Response равен 200(ответ ОК от сайта)

Comment: соответственно, если респонс не равен 200, значит сайт ответил некорректно(он ответил что то, но не то что надо для работы), мы не возвращаем ответ потоку, и генерируется exeption который в моих надеждах должен был выдавать string что написал сайт, но вместо этого он возаращет Null. пустую строку

Comment: Я не про `checkResponseCode`, а про то какое по факту туда попадает значение (`conn.getResponseCode`) перед возникновением ошибки. Судя по исключению, `checkResponseCode` вернул true.

Comment: а, часто это случалось когда getResponseCode() = 404, или 400

Comment: вон в вопросе он создает такой exception : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 , т.е. он туда кидал 400

Comment: Для 400 метод вернул бы false и никакого исключения бы не было. Выведите код прямо в методе: `System.out.println(responseCode);`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75979/discussion-between-default-locale-and-mrwatcher).

Comment: Основная проблема осталась в том что он выкидывает  java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: ***(Любой) когда response ! = 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем правильный ответ:
Чтобы получить ответ сайта при response != 200 , надо

```
else System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream())).readLine());
```

т.е. другой поток conn.getErrorStream().