# Java рекурсия stackoverflow exception

Tags: java, исключения, рекурсия

В программе существует несколько синхронизированных потоков, каждый из них рекурсивен, и создает новый объект который содержит в себе примерно такой код:

```
private String getAnswer(){
    URL aURL = new URL(link);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();
    if(checkResponseCode(conn.getResponseCode())) return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())).readLine();
}
```

Этот код обращается по `url`, который передает поток, и идет к *API* на сайте, получает *JSON* `string` И возвращает его потоку который создал объект.

---

**Вопрос:**

1 . Рано или поздно программа вылетает с `stackoverflow` на моменте `HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
```

Как исправить ошибку?

---

UPD: 
куда ведет  checkResponseCode(conn.getResponseCode())

```
private boolean checkResponseCode(int responcecode){
        if (responcecode >= 400 && responcecode < 500 && responcecode != 429 && responcecode != 418) {
            System.out.println("BAD REQUEST");
            return false;
        }
        if (responcecode >= 500 && responcecode < 600 && responcecode != 504) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
            return false;
        }
        switch (responcecode) {
            case 429:
                System.out.println("WARNING! REQUESTLIMIT FULL");
                return false;
            case 418:
                System.out.println("WARNING! IP BLOCK");
                return false;
            case 504:
                System.out.println("WARNING!FAILED");
                return false;
            case 200:
                return true;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ops. Help me! I don't know what i do now!");
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может на первом сконцентрироваться? Второй все равно слабее расписан (попробуйте проверить [`HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode()))

Comment: Там простой if со свичом который возвращает true или false добавил в шапку с вопросом

Comment: Все-таки нужно оставить один вопрос, а второй задать отдельно. Иначе оба вопроса будут разрастаться в разные стороны.

Comment: Если говорить про второй, когда Response false(Т.е. согласно свичу любой респонс который != 200, тогда он получает NullPointerExeption и в try\catch пытается вывести строку, но она то null для него. А если в линуксе через curl сделать запрос с ошибкой ты мы получим ответ 404 not found , а респонс нам какраз не виден.

Comment: Так и было изначально но он остался без ответа :(( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808557/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-request-https-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: про stackoverflow - зачем вообще используется рекурсия? и, кажется, тут не весь stacktrace

Comment: Рекурсия используется т.к. данные которые сайт отдает постоянно обновляются, а поток делает математические расчеты, и если не находит нужного ответа, берет новые данные и снова делает расчеты,  stacktrace действительно не полный, там множество раз повторяется моя рекурсия в стактрейсе, каждый метод который я вызывал, и останавливатсется на моем методе вызова урл в этой строке HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();

Comment: Понятно. Сочувствую, но дублировать вопросы нельзя. Сделайте, пожалуйста, по одному вопросу на публикацию. Можете попробовать дописать старый, а сдесь оставить про StackOverflow. Либо удалить старый, а StackOverflow вынести в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Понял, исправил..

Comment: @MrWatcher `checkResponseCode` тоже логичнее перенести.

Comment: @MrWatcher, так не проще в цикле это делать? конечно рекурсия рано или поздно выкинет stackoverflow, если постоянно углубляться

Comment: Вариант, но тогда я не понимаю смысла чем цикл будет отличаться от рекурсии? Цикл начнется заново, а рекурсия просто вызовет себя снова в конце?

Answer (score 4):

Итак ответ:
 default locale и  Никита Гордеев были правы,
вместо того чтобы делать вечную рекурсию(по задумке), в java это необходимо сделать циклом, и тогда ошибки переполненного стека не будет.

Comment: И не только в Java, рекурсия хорошо выглядит только на бумаге. В реальности рекурсивные алгоритмы в 100% случаев безопаснее сделать циклом с условием выхода по достижению результата

Comment: С рекурсией все в порядке, в функциональном программировании часто используется и очень часто рекурсивные решения намного красивее и понятнее цикличных. Но для этого нужен язык, который поддерживает "Tail recursion optimization", когда хвостовая рекурсия разворачивается в цикл. Например Scala, Kotlin. А Java это не поддерживает.

Comment: в скале не всегда есть возможность развернуть рекурсию в цикл, там есть некоторые ограничения